# How can I set the default site address for the Moodle Mobile and redirect to the Moodle site?

Tags: ionic-framework, moodle-mobile

I am using Moodle Mobile, and when I run the ionic it takes me to the home page where I can enter the Moodle site URL.

How can I change the home page, and make it to redirect to the default URL?

Thanks in advance
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to config.json and provide your site's url in "siteurl" property.
Then run the command 'ionic serve --browser chromium-browser' from your moodle mobile directory.